# Laravel accessing hasMany of hasOne

Tags: php, laravel, web, web-applications, frameworks

I have Room, Gallery and Images. I want to associate a gallery to the room and then I want to access the Images of the assigned Gallery using the Room model. I'm new into Laravel, I looked in YouTube lessons, and the documentation but didn't found out a solution for my problem.

**Room.php:**

```
class Room extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'rooms';

    public function gallery()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Gallery');
    }
}
```

**Gallery.php:**

```
class Gallery extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'gallery';

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
    }

    public function room()
    {
        return this->belongsTo('App\Room');
    }
}
```

**RoomController.php:**

```
$room = Room::findOrFail($id);
$room_gallery = $room->gallery()->images;
return $room_gallery;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Eloquent relationships, you access them as properties to access the related model(s) or access the method to query or perform additional manipulation.

Since you want a gallery model and it's related image models, you would access the properties of both:

```
$room_gallery = $room->gallery->images;
```

With a HasOne, `$room->gallery` is essentially equal to `$room->gallery()->first()`.  With HasMany, `$gallery->images` would be essentially equal to `$gallery->images()->get()`.

However, this may be a case where the [HasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship would come in handy.